# Read binary file into struct, handle char [8], using C

Tags: c, struct, binary

I have the following code, which prints out the binary perfectly (prints the first 4 characters (I'm guessing 2 bits per character, so 8 chars in total?

```
void myChunks(){

    struct chunkStorage
    {
        long sxID;
        char chunk[8];      // ‘Chunk of Data’

    };

        FILE *p;
        struct chunkStorage d;
        p=fopen("myfile.txt","rb");
        while(1){
            fread(&d.chunk,sizeof(d.chunk),1,p);
            if(feof(p)!=0)
                break;
            printf(“%s”, d.chunk);
            }
    fclose(p);
}
myChunks();
```

So the only way for me to be able to get at the data, seems to be using a while loop in this way. I'm wondering how I can concatenate this, and also hex encode it?

What does the char chunk[8] do? Why do I have to loop over each 8 bytes? Why cant I just forget the "while" loops and just read the full chunk after the fopen statement and then convert the full data to hex?

Is it right to concatenate, to get the full file, or is this likely to be erroneous?

Comment: Start with stopping using illegal (at least in standard C) characters `“` and `”` instead of `"`.

Comment: Read the result of `fread()` to avoid problems.  Code does not know it read 8 `char`.

Comment: In `printf("%s", d.chunk);` how do you ensure you have the `nul` terminated string required by `printf`?

Comment: *Why do I have to loop over each 8 bytes?* I don't know, why do you? You also have undefined behavior since you read 8 bytes and give it to printf as a null terminated string without null terminating it.

Comment: Could use `printf(“%.8s”, d.chunk);` to limit output to 8 `char`, even without a null character - but this still hides previous problems.

Comment: Sorry am a bit new to all this, how do I null terminate the string in the context of my code? Any examples for this? How will that actually get me closer to getting a hex encode of the whole binary file????

Comment: You ask for examples, yet do not provide examples to your post.  Post example input data and expected output.

Comment: As I say, the output is expected, it's just that it prints out line by line (8 chars at a time). i just want the whole file in one variable, so I can hex encode the whole thing. Is there really no way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the history of this file, or the other parts of the structure that are defined, but from a strict `C` standpoint, the file is simply a large quantity of 8 byte values, with nulls in them (or else the `printf` would be completely invalid.)

So yes, the following is possible if your code is valid:

```
typedef struct justchunk { char chunk[8] ; } chunker ;
chunker * ptr ;

ptr= (chunker * ) malloc( 1000000 * sizeof( chunker ) ) ;
int iret ;
f= fopen( "myfile.txt", "rb") ;
iret= fread( ptr, sizeof( chunker), 1000000, f) ;
```

The value returned in `iret` will be how many complete records were read.

Error handling, and file closing left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Hi, iret is an int? My data is char?

Comment: @Ke. The man page for [`fread`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) ...

Comment: but why do I need how many complete records? I'm after the data inside the chunk, not the amount of records...

Comment: but why do I need how many complete records? I'm after the data inside the chunk, not the amount of records...

Comment: I was guessing that there was more than a single 8 byte record in the file and that you would eventually need to look at more than one of them.  If not, you can ignore the return value, except to check that you read at least one.